# sum of elements using while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to get a sum of all elements using while loop.

```
from numpy import *
x = array([1, 23, 43, 72, 87, 56, 98, 33])
def sum_x(x):
    sum = 0
    for i in x:
        sum += i
    return sum
print(sum_x(x))
```

This is the code I made for 'for loop'.
I would like to change it to 'while loop' code.
Please help me out!
I have no idea how to add an element to an element in while loop.

Comment: It works with print(sum_x()). I am getting same result as sum(x).

Comment: Oh I missed a line which is (sum += i). However, I just figured it out the answer thanks tho.

Comment: I fixed a code in the question. It may look ugly, but it works.

Comment: You don't need numpy or array for this. A regular (built-in) list works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Clean while loop:

```
def sum_x(x):
    i = 0
    res = 0
    while i < len(x):
        res += x[i]
        i += 1
    return res

>>> sum_x(np.arange(100))
4950
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to use any looping structure, just use:

```
x = array([1, 23, 43, 72, 87, 56, 98, 33])
print(sum(x))
```